# Java streams to compare between objects and return that object?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have an `ArrayList` of a class object like below:

```
ArrayList<Score> scoreboard = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `Score` class has a field `points`:

```
class Score {
    private int points; 
    //constructor and methods
}
```

How would i go about using Java streams to compare the `points` in each of this `Score` object and return the object with the highest/lowest value?

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
scoreboard
    .stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Score::getPoints)
    .get()
    .forEach(System::println);
```

Comment: define _not working_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look carefully at what you tried:

```
scoreboard.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Score::getPoints).get().forEach(System::println);
```

Here, you're trying to create a `Comparator`:

```
Comparator.comparing(Score::getPoints).get().forEach(System::println)
```

and you've not balanced the parentheses; and you're using a non-existent method, `System::println`.

Put the parentheses in the right place:

```
Score maxScore = scoreboard.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Score::getPoints)).get();
                                                                        // Extra  ^
```

Then print it:

```
System.out.println(maxScore);
```

Or, if you're not sure that the stream is non-empty:

```
Optional<Score> opt = scoreboard.stream().max(...);
opt.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```